# Join three tables, select only positive amount from second table + first and latest date from third table

Tags: sql, join, greatest-n-per-group, firebird, firebird2.5

I need this result for each Product.

```
Product ID                  Date             Amount
ID1                         10.01.21         3
ID2                         15.04.22         2
ID3                         NULL             NULL
```

From these 3 Tables

```
Products                    Order List                         Order
ID  SKU                     ProductID  OrderID  Amount         OrderID    Date
ID1 ProductA                ID1        Order1  -5              Order1     12.03.22
ID2 ProductB                ID1        Order2   3              Order2     10.01.21
ID3 ProductC                ID2        Order3   2              Order3     15.04.22
```

For each Product I only want the first positive value from the second table (Order List Table) and the latest and first order Date from table 3 (Order Table).

Following would be wrong even though its the latest, but the amount is -5 (not positive)

```
ID1, 12.03.22, -5
```

So far, I got

```sql
SELECT
  Product.ID,
  OrderList.Amount,
  Order.Date
FROM
  Product
  INNER JOIN OrderList ON OrderList.ProductID = Product.ID
  INNER JOIN Order ON OrderList.OrderID = Order.ID
```

I tried several min() or Min distinct, left join etc, but never got any result like this.

Comment: The provided testdata is inconsistent (e.g. orderlist references an product with ID2, but you didn't define it in products) and insufficient to demonstrate the actual problem (due to lack of sufficient example data). Assuming you meant ID1 instead of ID2, adding a where clause with `orderlist.amount > 0` will already produce your desired result, but that is unlikely to be the solution you really need.

Comment: Please update your question to provide the necessary DDL and DML to setup the test data, and make sure it has multiple products, multiple orders with the latest date, multiple orders with different dates, and multiple orders with positive amounts, and then show us the expected result for that test-data. For example, right now, I'm wondering: do you want one result in total, one result per product, all positive results on the highest date, or something else.

Comment: >orderlist references an product with ID2   ---  Yes, you are right I just changed that, it should be ID1

Comment: >orderlist.amount > 0         ---- Yes but it also should be the latest Order which means if I ordered today last week and a month ago it should ONLY show the order from today but only if its positive if not for example the order from last week if its positiv.

Comment: That sounds like select where amount > 0, order by date desc and select the first record (using [`FIRST`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-select-first-skip). If that isn't what you want, you really need to provide more testdata and expected results for that testdata and explain in detail your selection criteria.

Comment: First does not work I need for each Produt the Order Informations from the second and thrid table.

Comment: So what does it need to select only the latest (Date) and first result from the second table?

Answer (score 0):

If - as mentioned in the comments - you only need a record from orderlist with a positive amount from the most recent order with a positive amount, you can use:

```sql
select first 1 p.ID, p.SKU, ol.AMOUNT, o.ORDERDATE
from ORDERS o 
inner join ORDERLIST ol on o.ORDERID = ol.ORDERID 
inner join PRODUCTS p on p.ID = ol.PRODUCTID 
where ol.AMOUNT > 0
order by o.ORDERDATE desc
```

This will only return a single record, even if that latest order has more than one orderlist record with a positive amount.

If on the other hand you want all orderlist records with a positive amount from the most recent order with positive amount, you can use:

```sql
select p.ID, p.SKU, ol.AMOUNT, o.ORDERDATE
from (
  select first 1 orders.ORDERID, orders.ORDERDATE  
  from ORDERS
  where exists (
    select * 
    from ORDERLIST 
    where orderlist.ORDERID = orders.ORDERID and orderlist.AMOUNT > 0)
  order by orders.ORDERDATE desc
) o
inner join ORDERLIST ol on o.ORDERID = ol.ORDERID 
inner join PRODUCTS p on p.ID = ol.PRODUCTID 
where ol.AMOUNT > 0
```

With the modified requirement specified in the comments:

> I actually first need ALL SKU IDs and for each SKU ID one order and
> one Items from the order List, but the newest and not negative.

you can do something like this with Firebird 2.5:

```sql
with recentproduct as (
  select ol.productid, max(o.orderdate) as orderdate
  from orders o 
  inner join orderlist ol on o.orderid = ol.orderid
  where ol.amount > 0
  group by ol.productid
)
select p.id as productid, p.sku, ol.orderid, ol.amount 
from products p
left join (
  recentproduct rp
  inner join orderlist ol on rp.productid = ol.productid and ol.amount > 0
  inner join orders o on o.orderdate = rp.orderdate and o.orderid = ol.orderid
) on p.id = rp.productid
```

Be aware, this solution is not perfect: if there are multiple orders for the same product on a single date, this will return all of them. This is easier solved in Firebird 3.0 and higher using window functions.

Comment: I am very sorry, now I see why you where asking for more Data.

Comment: So I actually first need ALL SKU IDs and for each SKU ID one order and one Items from the order List, but the newest and not negative.